# С++ WinAPI ошибка при GetOpenFileName

Tags: winapi, c++

Доброго времени суток.
Я сделал класс для работы OpenFileDialog:

```
#include <Windows.h>

enum DialogResult { OK, Cancel };

class IFileDialog
{
public: 
    TCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];
    LPTSTR Title;
    virtual DialogResult Show() = 0;
};

class COpenFileDialog  : public IFileDialog
{
public:
    LPTSTR Filter;
    LPTSTR DefExt;
    COpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd);
    DialogResult Show();
private:
    OPENFILENAME m_ofn;
};

COpenFileDialog::COpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd)
{
    //FileName[0] = '\0';

    ZeroMemory(&m_ofn, sizeof(m_ofn));

    m_ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(m_ofn);
    m_ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    m_ofn.lpstrFilter = Filter;
    m_ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    m_ofn.lpstrFile = FileName;
    m_ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    m_ofn.lpstrDefExt = DefExt;
}

DialogResult COpenFileDialog::Show()
{
    return GetOpenFileName(&m_ofn) ? DialogResult::OK : DialogResult::Cancel;
}
```

Затем пытаюсь вызвать:

```
COpenFileDialog hDialog = COpenFileDialog(hMainWindow);
hDialog.Filter = "M&B Scenes\0*.sco\0";
hDialog.DefExt = "sco";
hDialog.Title = "";

if(hDialog.Show() == DialogResult::OK)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Но прога крушиться на `hDialog.Show()`, а точнее при вызове `GetOpenFileName(&m_ofn)`:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FDFC5D21A3 (SHCore.dll) in
>   ScoEditor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000000E600000000.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Может дело в указателях?

```
LPTSTR Title;
LPTSTR Filter;
LPTSTR DefExt;
```

Ведь по сути вы их не инициализировали, а просто пытаетесь присвоить строку. По логике так делать нельзя. Необходимо выделять память под эти указатели (ну и соответственно потом ее удалять).

```
LPTSTR pBuffer; // TCHAR* 
pBuffer = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
...
delete[] pBuffer;
```

Попробуйте жестко указать эти параметры, при инициализации структуры:

```
m_ofn.lpstrFilter = Filter;
m_ofn.lpstrDefExt = DefExt;
m_ofn.lpstrFileTitle = Title;
```

Ссылка на MSDN - [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#open_file)

Answer (score 0):

Где-то при инициализации структуры `m_ofn` есть ошибка, передаете не то что надо, или что-то не объявлено.